# HTML se ve diferente entre firefox y chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

El `margin-top` de los elementos internos de mi contenedor en Firefox no se ve, mientras que en Chrome sí se ve, dejo imágenes adjuntas:

[image: La de arriba es en firefox y no se ve el margin-top como en Chrome que es el de abajo.]

EL código es el siguiente:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.initWrapPages {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.initPage img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
}

.initPagesText {
  height: 10%;
}

.initPagesText h4 {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.initPagesText p {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.initPagesText a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.initPage {
  background: #D2D9D2;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="initWrapPages">
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>'FALKLANDS WAR' el tema que está dando que hablar!</h4>
      <p>Acabamos de lanzar el primer single de nuestro EP/LP 'Below The Lines' vol I, la acogida del público es destacable, te preguntarás ¿PORQUÉ? pues que no te lo cuenten míralo tu mismo, vamos!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>NUEVAS CAMISETAS DISPONIBLES!</h4>
      <p>Hemos actualizado nuestro merchandising con las nuevas camisetas recién adquiridas, con un diseño que a todos os va a gustar!, hecho por nuestro colaborador Pepito, tenéis los precios y promos disponibles en esta sección!, no lo dudes y entra!</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>Disponible 'Below The Lines' vol I</h4>
      <p>La primera parte de nuestro LP ha sido subido a las redes para el disfrute de todo el público, además de escuchar los nuevos temas podréis obtener free download del vol I, </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>Nuestro Team</h4>
      <p>No siempre trabajamos solos, siempre tenemos ayuda a nivel multimedia y fotografico de nuestro equipo que siempre están apoyando la música, entra y conócelos, te pueden interesar!</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

¿Por qué ocurre eso y cómo puedo hacer que se vea igual en ambos navegadores?

Comment: Bienvenido @ilion_2017. Va a ser complicado que alguien pueda ayudarte sin ver el código.

Comment: cierto, lo edito ahora mismo :D

Comment: listo, ya puse el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dar solución a tu problema yo agregaría un `padding-top` al padre (`.initWrapPages`) del mismo valor que tiene el `margin-top` de los contenedores hijos (`.initPage`) y éstos últimos les quitaría el `margin-top`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.initWrapPages {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

.initPage img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
}

.initPagesText {
  height: 10%;
}

.initPagesText h4 {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.initPagesText p {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.initPagesText a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.initPage {
  background: #D2D9D2;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="initWrapPages">
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>'FALKLANDS WAR' el tema que está dando que hablar!</h4>
      <p>Acabamos de lanzar el primer single de nuestro EP/LP 'Below The Lines' vol I, la acogida del público es destacable, te preguntarás ¿PORQUÉ? pues que no te lo cuenten míralo tu mismo, vamos!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>NUEVAS CAMISETAS DISPONIBLES!</h4>
      <p>Hemos actualizado nuestro merchandising con las nuevas camisetas recién adquiridas, con un diseño que a todos os va a gustar!, hecho por nuestro colaborador Pepito, tenéis los precios y promos disponibles en esta sección!, no lo dudes y entra!</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>Disponible 'Below The Lines' vol I</h4>
      <p>La primera parte de nuestro LP ha sido subido a las redes para el disfrute de todo el público, además de escuchar los nuevos temas podréis obtener free download del vol I, </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="initPage">
    <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
    <div class="initPagesText">
      <h4>Nuestro Team</h4>
      <p>No siempre trabajamos solos, siempre tenemos ayuda a nivel multimedia y fotografico de nuestro equipo que siempre están apoyando la música, entra y conócelos, te pueden interesar!</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba aplicarle el `margin-top:10%` a `initWrapPages` y no a `initPage` puesto que el anterior es el padre y es quien debe ir separado. Te quedaria así:

```
.initWrapPages {
position: relative;
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10%;
padding-bottom: 1000px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
```

}

```
.initPage {
 background: #D2D9D2;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 width: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-right: 2%;  
 border-radius: 3px 3px 2px 2px;
```

}

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo había pensado pero mientras dormía, pero tenéis toda la razón y ha funcionado perfectamente como quería, muchísimas gracias a los dos.

Comment: Al parecer los valores en el margin con poercentajes no lo reconoce (Firefox), probé por curiosidad en pixeles y si surgió efecto.

Answer (score 1):

El problema ocurre por cómo estás definiendo los márgenes usando porcentajes, y a que el contenedor (`initWrapPages`) tiene `display:flex`. Y no es un problema con tu código en sí, sino con la manera de interpretarlo que tiene cada navegador.

Como se explica en [esta respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3695983), cuando se usa flexbox, Chrome y Safari resuelven los porcentajes de la altura de los elementos flex basándose en la propiedad `height` del padre. En cambio, Firefox e IE11/Edge dan prioridad a la altura flex del padre.

Es por eso que si defines la altura del padre (`initWrapPages`) a un valor concreto, aunque eso puede no valerte en tu caso en concreto. Otra posible solución sería añadir `padding-top` al padre (como te comentan en otra respuesta).

Y otra posible solución sería añadir un `div` intermedio dentro de `.initWrapPages` que contenga los `.initPage`, y al que moverías los estilos `flex`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.initWrapPages {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;

}

.initWrapPagesContainer {
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.initPage img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
}

.initPagesText {
  height: 10%;
}

.initPagesText h4 {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

.initPagesText p {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.initPagesText a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.initPage {
  background: #D2D9D2;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 2px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="initWrapPages">
  <div class="initWrapPagesContainer">
    <div class="initPage">
      <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
      <div class="initPagesText">
        <h4>'FALKLANDS WAR' el tema que está dando que hablar!</h4>
        <p>Acabamos de lanzar el primer single de nuestro EP/LP 'Below The Lines' vol I, la acogida del público es destacable, te preguntarás ¿PORQUÉ? pues que no te lo cuenten míralo tu mismo, vamos!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="initPage">
      <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
      <div class="initPagesText">
        <h4>NUEVAS CAMISETAS DISPONIBLES!</h4>
        <p>Hemos actualizado nuestro merchandising con las nuevas camisetas recién adquiridas, con un diseño que a todos os va a gustar!, hecho por nuestro colaborador Pepito, tenéis los precios y promos disponibles en esta sección!, no lo dudes y entra!</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="initPage">
      <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
      <div class="initPagesText">
        <h4>Disponible 'Below The Lines' vol I</h4>
        <p>La primera parte de nuestro LP ha sido subido a las redes para el disfrute de todo el público, además de escuchar los nuevos temas podréis obtener free download del vol I, </p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="initPage">
      <img src="img/home/image_default.png">
      <div class="initPagesText">
        <h4>Nuestro Team</h4>
        <p>No siempre trabajamos solos, siempre tenemos ayuda a nivel multimedia y fotografico de nuestro equipo que siempre están apoyando la música, entra y conócelos, te pueden interesar!</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```